# The maximum length of a Datagram Packet is 65,536 or 65,535?

Tags: networking, udp

I found both answers on the internet.

I think it should be 2 bytes = 2^16 = 65,536, but on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) it is written that it is 65,535 :

> The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes (8-byte header + 65,527 bytes of data) for a UDP datagram.

Why is 1 byte missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609561/udp-maximum-packet-size

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio "IPv4 has a theoretical maximum packet size of 65,535 (a 16-bit total length field in the IPv4 header" But 16-bit = 65,536 and not 65,535. It doesn't explain why is 1 byte missing.

Comment: 0 is smallest, 65535 is largest 16 bit number

Comment: 16-bit is not 65536. It's like saying that "the largest 2-digit number is 100". Sure, there are 100 different numbers that fit in 2 digits (starting with 0) but the largest of them is 99, not 100. Similarly, the largest value that fits in 16 bits is 65535.

Comment: Okay, but I've always talked about the max size, not the max value. In this case, it is 65.536. Right?

Comment: @Denis: No – that would only be true if the value indicated "position" (such as disk sector addresses), but that's not the case here. In IP, the header indicates length, so a value of "65535" doesn't mean the last byte position is 65535 – it says there are 65535 bytes in total. (Search for "Fencepost error" about the difference.)

Comment: @user1686 ahhhh I got it! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reddy's hit the nail on the head: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609561/udp-maximum-packet-size

The maximum IP packet size is 65,535 bytes (2<sup>16</sup>-1), including all headers and usually requiring fragmentation. Assuming standard headers, IPv4 uses 20 bytes and UDP 8 bytes. The resulting **maximum UDP payload size over IPv4 is 65,507 bytes**. The maximum UDP datagram includes the UDP header and is 65,515 bytes. For completeness, UDP over IPv6 is 20 bytes less.

If you tried to leverage the theoretical maximum UDP datagram length of 65,535 bytes you couldn't use IP to transport it with.

65,535 is the maximum value you can store in 16 bits - the largest number is binary `1111 1111 1111 1111` = decimal 65,535. There are 65,536 different values, including `0000 0000 0000 0000`.

Answer (score 0):

The length field is 16 bit and can thus represent sizes between 0 and 65535. Wikipedia and others are right .